# How to use preinstalled software in GitHub actions

Tags: c++, github, cmake, github-actions

### Issue Background

I am setting up CI environment for my pet project on GitHub. I want to have actions that test the project on different OS *(Windows, Linux, macOS)* using different compilers *(gcc, Clang, MSVC)*, in other words to ensure that the project supports certain toolkits.

### The problem

There are lists of preinstalled software on the GitHub runners for each OS. Since some of needed software is already preinstalled (and its version is frequently updated), I want to use it in the GitHub actions in order to not spend time on installation. But how do I use them?

To specify compiler during configuration with CMake `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="path/to/compiler/bin"` option can be used in cmake CLI command. This way the string in quotes can be either the path or environmental variable. I inspected the environmental variables on Windows runner and found out that the path to the MinGW-w64 compiler path is enlisted in the PATH variable. How can I use it?

### GitHub documentation

From GitHub actions [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#using-preinstalled-software):

> #### Using preinstalled software
>
> We recommend using actions to interact with the software installed on runners. This approach has several benefits:
>
> - Usually, actions provide more flexible functionality like versions selection, ability to pass arguments, and parameters
> - It ensures the tool versions used in your workflow will remain the same regardless of software updates
>
> If there is a tool that you'd like to request, please open an issue at actions/runner-images. This repository also contains announcements about all major software updates on runners.

But I did not find any action for MinGW-w64 compiler interaction.

### The question

Is there a way to use preinstalled software in such a way? How can I get the path to the binary in order to specify it for CMake? Are there any actions for interacting with compilers that I missed?

### Update 1:

As [@Sedenion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3740047/sedenion) pointed out, the solution for Windows is to use [MSYS2 action](https://github.com/msys2/setup-msys2), which IMO is still downloading something and does not solve the initial issue "to use preinstalled software". And there still are Linux and macOS to find solution for.

Comment: I think for mingw you are supposed to use msys2 for this, see e.g. [here](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/discussions/5291). At least this is [how I did it](https://github.com/Sedeniono/tiny-optional/blob/main/.github/workflows/test_gcc_win.yml).

Comment: @Sedenion thanks for the response. MSYS2 can be used for Windows but which methods/actions one should use for Linux and macOS? I will edit the question to bring this up too